# Which of these equality-with-conversion cases is an error, if any?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

Consider the following:

```
using System;

struct FooEnum {
    public static implicit operator TypeCode(FooEnum foo) { return TypeCode.Empty; }
}

struct FooDelegate {
    public static implicit operator EventHandler(FooDelegate foo) { return null; }
}

struct FooInt {
    public static implicit operator int(FooInt foo) { return 0; }
}

class Foo {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(new FooEnum() == new FooEnum());  // CS0019
        Console.WriteLine(new FooDelegate() == new FooDelegate());  // OK
        Console.WriteLine(new FooInt() == new FooInt());    // OK
    }
}
```

Compiling this will produce

> Error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'FooEnum' and 'FooEnum'

Tested with VC# 2005 8.0.50727.8745, csc 4.6.1586.0, Roslyn 1.3.2 and Roslyn 2.0.0-rc2. The result is the same in all cases.

Per the [C# language specification 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), §7.10:

> For an operation of the form `x op y`, where op is a
>   comparison operator, overload resolution (§7.3.4) is applied to select
>   a specific operator implementation. The operands are converted to the
>   parameter types of the selected operator, and the type of the result
>   is the return type of the operator.

There exist predefined operators for all enum types (§7.10.5), all delegate types (§7.10.8) and for `int` (§7.10.1). Binary operator overload resolution (§7.3.4) specifies that, since none of the `Foo` types define their own equality operator,

> ... the predefined binary operator *op* implementations, including their
>   lifted forms, become the set of candidate operators for the
>   operation. The predefined implementations of a given operator are
>   specified in the description of the operator (§7.8 through §7.12).
>   **For predefined enum and delegate operators, the only operators considered are those defined by an enum or delegate type that is the binding-time type of one of the operands.**

(Here "binding-time" means compile-time, since no `dynamic` expressions are involved.)

The highlighted sentence seems to explain why the implicit conversion to `TypeCode` is not considered when selecting the overload (and hence why the `FooEnum` case is invalid), but, by the same token, the `FooDelegate` case should be invalid, and that's invoked just fine. (`FooInt` is the boring case to demonstrate that implicit conversions to predefined operators are considered.)

Am I reading the spec correctly in that the `FooDelegate` comparison should produce an error as well? If not, by what sequence of rules is that allowed (assuming the compiler is correct) and why does that sequence not allow `FooEnum` (if that is not obvious)?

Comment: Plainly something weird is going on here, and I do not have the time or the tools right now to diagnose what is going on here.  Suffice to say that it was my intention when I wrote the code that this would not resolve to the delegate comparison, and I don't know offhand how it is happening that it is.  I'll try to find some time tonight to look into it.

Comment: Adding evidence to the hypothesis that something is wrong in the compiler: your equality expression produces an "expression is always true" warning on Mac Visual Studio; if this is in fact doing delegate comparison (as it appears to be) then plainly it is *not* always true. So there are possibly multiple bugs here.

Comment: And FYI it should be clear why enum and delegate operators are restricted in this way. We must not start with an *infinite* set of *possibly applicable* equality operators and then winnow that down to a finite set of actually applicable operators! We have to start with a finite set, so saying that we only consider those enum / delegate types that are already "involved" is the natural way to do that.

Comment: Well, *this* implementation returns a constant `null` for the delegate, so yes, the comparison is always true. A smart compiler could see that, I suppose?

Comment: FWIW, `new FooEnum() == TypeCode.Empty` (and v.v.) is fine, as is `new FooEnum() == (TypeCode)new FooEnum()` (and v.v.), as is the original if `FooEnum` is a class instead of a struct.  (By "is fine" I just mean the compiler is happy with it).

Comment: @sellotape: yes, none of those scenarios run afoul of the original rule.

Comment: @EricLippert: I see your point about the infinite set, but clearly, only those delegate and enum types for which a conversion actually exists could be involved, so the set should easily be limited from that end. (Unless it's easier to pull in conversions somehow than I'm thinking.) I was a little surprised this *didn't* work for enum types, really.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I changed your example so that it was returning unequal delegates instead of null and it still gave the warning. Something is broken.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Things get more complicated when you throw the fact that delegates can be covariant and contravariant, and the operands can themselves be generics, into the mix. Yes, there are ways to work all these problems out, and compiler writers frankly have a lot better things to do. It's better to come up with a simple rule that's easy to implement.  As we've seen with your example here, *the rule is already too complicated to be implemented correctly*. It should probably have been a lot simpler.

Comment: @EricLippert: I'll easily grant the point for delegates (just reading the rules is headache-inducing), but, if you're going to allow things like `FooInt`, and considering the enums are glorified lists of integer constants, it's harder to see why `FooEnum` should not be allowed -- unless you're talking about the cases where things like `FooEnum` are passed to delegates and we need to decide if those match the signature for enums, but this case does not seem to apply for binary operator overloading.

Comment: @EricLippert: having said that, if you were arguing to rewrite the rules for operator overloading such that even `FooInt` was not allowed, I really wouldn't disagree. I think C# is flexible to the point of craziness with this -- what's wrong with being explicit about your operators?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Amen brother, can I get a hallelujah? :-)

Comment: @EricLippert: do you want to follow up with something more substantial? I'm fine with an answer that simply says "you're reading the standard right and this is a bug by that measure", leaving the resolution (if there is to be any, given backwards compat considerations) up in the air.